# Increase the size of APT::Cache-Limit

Tags: linux

When I updated my Ubuntu system with update manager, I encountered an error, and now the update manager is stuck. The error message is:

> An unresolvable problem occurred while initializing the package
>   information.
>
> Please report this bug against the 'update-manager' package and
>   include the following error message:
>
> 'E:Dynamic MMap ran out of room. Please increase the size of
>   APT::Cache-Limit. Current value: 25165824. (man 5 apt.conf), E:Error
>   occurred while processing moonlight-tools (NewVersion1), E:Problem
>   with MergeList
>   /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_lucid-proposed_universe_binary-i386_Packages,
>   E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.'

I googled on how to increase the cache-limit, and changed `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf` to

```
APT::Cache-Limit "100000000"
```

But this solution doesn't work. The problem wasn't fixed.

What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: This question is off-topic and should be closed.  It's about general computing hardware and software.

Answer (score 6):

These steps worked for me in Ubuntu 16:

Add line `APT::Cache-Limit "100000000";` to file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf`

Delete all corrupted merge lists.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
```

Then running an update with following command will automatically create
 a good new `/var/lib/dpkg/status` file.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of adding the line `APT::Cache-Limit "100000000";` to the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf` add it to the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20archive` which solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20archive` and setting the max size and max age values?

Comment: Why do we have these different config files `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf` `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20archive` in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` ? Why different config files are working for different people?

Comment: they are run by the system at different points in the start up process

Comment: Ok. But do you have any idea why same config parameter APT::Cache-Limit needs to be configured in different file for different cases?

Comment: I thought you only needed it in one of the files

Answer (score 0):

You may attempt to clean the APT-list which may be corrupted, and then replace it with an existing, working one.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/status-bad
sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status-old /var/lib/dpkg/status
sudo apt-get update
```

You can try to refer here for more info: https://justinalex.com/ubuntu-fixing-the-apt-repository-and-package-manager-2/

Answer (score 0):

1/27/2017

Mepis 12 Variant:

When attempting to activate all the available repositories in Mepis 12, Synaptic will gripe,

"E: Dynamic MMap ran out of room. Please increase the size of APT::Cache-Start."

and crash out on exit, subsequently refusing to restart.

Mepis users who need the full spectrum of available repos should edit the content of the "80mepis" file in the /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/ directory to read

```
    APT::Cache-Limit "100000000";
```

as suggested for the /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf file in similar affected distros, as above. My Mepis 12 Final Edition installations have all, to date, required this fix in order to to enable a full complement of repositories on demand.

Heartfelt thanks to the others who have gone before.  As a longtime public Mepis installer, I think cleaning the system with

```
rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
mv /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/status-bad
cp /var/lib/dpkg/status-old /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

and then doing a

```
apt-get update
```

command from the command line, all as su (aka root),as suggested above, is a very good idea too.  And that is all.  0{:-)o[

Answer (score 0):

May be due to server resource limitation, setting   `APT::Cache-Limit "100000000";` didn't work for me.

My last resort stop resource intensive service for temporary and perform the upgrade.

Thanks,

Comment: The question is off-topic because it is a general hardware question.  [Do not advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions)